# string.search() throwing a javascript error 'object doesn't support prperty or method search'

Tags: javascript

I have searched all the other related questions but none the wiser.

I am using javascript to capture form data when reloading the form so I can read the data in $_GET in php.

It works fine unless there is an '&' in a string.  The code with my comments:

```
oSupps = form.elements["supps[]"]; 
//a multi-choice select element
var supps = getSelectedOptions(oSupps);
//returns a comma-separated list of selected items; this includes the correct string with
the ampersand
var params='supps='+supps;
//sets up the string to be returned to the page in the next line of code
self.location='instructor_register_2.inc?' + params;
```

The url shows the correct string with ampersand but the $_GET splits the string into 2 rows and loses the ampersand.

An example:

```
string is "Abercrombie & Fitch"
$_GET is:
supps   "Abercrombie"
Fitch   ""
```

I tried to check for the ampersand in the string and escape it in the javascript with:

```
needle=/&/
pos=supps.search(needle)
if(pos!=-1)
{
    newsupps=supps.replace(" & "," /& ");
    supps=newsupps;
}
```

but it will not get past the supps.search saying that 'the object doesn't support the property or method search'.

I'm using the inbuilt browser in PhpED version 8.1.

I cannot find any reference to search (and probably replace) not being supported in any specific browsers and they are included in all basic javascript tutorials that I can find.

Any ideas please

Comment: Seems like there's a very good chance `supps` is not a string. Try adding `console.log(typeof supps)` before attempting `search`. My guess is `getSelectedOptions()` returns an array

Comment: have you tried to encode your `params` string? `encodeURIComponent(params)`

Comment: can you try this `console.log("Abercrombie".search(/&/))` and let us know the output?

Comment: btw this seems to do all in one line `"Abercrombie & Fitch".replace(/(&)/g,"/$1")` note that use `g` to find all matches

Comment: Thanks guys but still no luck!

Comment: Not sure where console.log is sending its output but alert(typeof supps) returns object.

Comment: encodeURIComponent(params) has no effect

Comment: encodeURIComponent(params) does work - I put the edit in the wrong place!!.  Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the url component by calling [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
var params = 'supps=' + encodeURIComponent(supps);
```

Comment: This should definitely take care of the problem, even if `supps` is an array (it will be converted to a string in `encodeURIComponent`)

Comment: Sorry guys, an alert(params) after the encodeURI line gives 'undefined'

Comment: Oops, put the changed code in the wrong place - silly me.  It works - thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are using GET, so the ampersand indicates the end of an attribute. So "Fitch" is interpreted as the name of a new attribute, which has no value. Run `params = encodeURIComponent(params)` to escape all the URI specific chars.